# How does this approximation of division using bit shift operations work?

Tags: java, math, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

In `java.util.DualPivotQuicksort`, the following line of code appears:

```
// Inexpensive approximation of length / 7
int seventh = (length >> 3) + (length >> 6) + 1;
```

The variable `length` is an `int` greater than or equal to 47.

I am familiar with how the signed right shift operator works. But I do not know why these particular operations result in an approximation of division by 7. Could someone explain please?

Comment: What division is right-shifting by 3 equivalent to ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`>>` is bitshift. Every bit you shift right, in effect divides the number of 2.

Therefore, `(length >> 3)` is `length/8` (rounded down), and `(length >> 6)` is `length/64`.

Take `(length/8)+(length/64)` is approximately `length*(1/8+1/64)` = `length*0.140625` (approximately)

`1/7 = 0.142857...`

The `+1` at the end can be split into `+0.5` for each term, so that `length/8` is rounded to nearest (instead of down), and `length/64` is also rounded to nearest.

---

In general, you can easily approximate `1/y`, where `y = 2^n+-1` with a similar bit-shift approximation.

The infinite geometric series is:

```
1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... = 1 / (1 - x)
```

Multiplying by x:

```
x + x^2 + x^3 + ... = x/(1 - x)
```

And substituting `x = 1/2^n`

```
1/2^n + 1/2^2n + 1/2^3n + ... = (1/2^n) / (1 - 1/2^n)
1/2^n + 1/2^2n + 1/2^3n + ... = (1/2^n) / ((2^n - 1)/2^n)

1/2^n + 1/2^2n + 1/2^3n + ... = 1 / (2^n - 1)
```

This approximates `y = 2^n - 1`.

To approximate `y = 2^n + 1`, substitute `x = -1/2^n` instead.

```
- 1/2^n + 1/2^2n - 1/2^3n + ... = (-1/2^n) / (1 + 1/2^n)
1/2^n - 1/2^2n + 1/2^3n - ... = (1/2^n) / ((2^n + 1)/2^n)

1/2^n - 1/2^2n + 1/2^3n - ... = 1 / (2^n + 1)
```

Then just truncate the infinite series to the desired accuracy.

Comment: I see. How about the addition of 1 at the end, is that to "balance out" the rounding down?

Comment: Yeah, it adds half to length/8, and half to length/64, so on average, they are round to nearest instead of round down.

Answer (score 3):

Set `x = 1/8` in the  well-known equality

```
1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... = 1 / (1 - x)
```

and simplify, to give

```
1/8 + 1/64 + 1/512 + ...  = 1/7
```

Multiply both sides of this by `length` in your example, to give

```
length / 7 = length / 8 + length / 64 + length / 512 + ...
```

Note that this is "exact" division, not integer division - I'm writing mathematics, not Java code.

Then the approximation assumes that the third and subsequent terms will be too small to matter, and that on average one  of `length / 8` and `length / 64` is likely to need rounding up, rather than rounding down. So, now using integer division, `length / 7 = length / 8 + length / 64 + 1` is a very good approximation.

The expression you gave, using bitwise operators, is just an alternative way of writing this, provided `length` is positive.

Answer (score 2):

To put a mathematical background to ronalchn's answer:

Since 7=8-1=8*(1-1/8), by the geometric series division by 7 is the same as multiplication by

> 1/7 = 1/8·(1+1/8+1/8²+1/8³+…) = 1/8+1/8²+1/8³+…

---

To do the same for the division by 5, one would use that 3·5=16-1 and thus

> 1/5 = 3/16·(1+1/16+1/16²+…)

which would invite a formula like

```
(3*n)<<4 + (3*n) << 8 + 1
```

Comment: For `1/5`, multiplication is not necessarily cheap, so a better approximation might be `1/4-1/16+1/64-1/256+...`

Comment: Yes, that is probably better, even if you need more terms for it. The compiler could optimize these successive bit-shifts by reusing the last shifted value.

Answer (score 1):

Computing all values of

```
n/8 + n/64 - n/7
```

the error grows linearly, while staying negative.

The list below shows the first time a given error appears

```
n = 7 e = -1
n = 63 e = -2
n = 511 e = -3
n = 959 e = -4
n = 1407 e = -5
n = 1855 e = -6
n = 2303 e = -7
n = 2751 e = -8
n = 3199 e = -9
n = 3647 e = -10
n = 4095 e = -11
n = 4543 e = -12
n = 4991 e = -13
n = 5439 e = -14
n = 5887 e = -15
n = 6335 e = -16
n = 6783 e = -17
n = 7231 e = -18
n = 7679 e = -19
n = 8127 e = -20
n = 8575 e = -21
n = 9023 e = -22
n = 9471 e = -23
n = 9919 e = -24
...
```

The ratio obviously tends to `1/448 = 1/8 + 1/64 - 1/7`.